# MySQL generated .sql Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-workbench

This is the table I get "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Supervise1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Supervise1` (
  `S1_Date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `S1_Contracter` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `S1_Contractee` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `S1_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S1_Contracter`, `S1_Contractee`, `S1_Date`, `S1_ID`),
  INDEX `Contracter_idx` (`S1_Contracter` ASC),
  INDEX `Contractee_idx` (`S1_Contractee` ASC),
  INDEX `S1_ID_idx` (`S1_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `S1_Date`
    FOREIGN KEY (`S1_Date`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Contract` (`Date`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `S1_Contracter`
    FOREIGN KEY (`S1_Contracter`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Contract` (`Contracter`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `S1_Contractee`
    FOREIGN KEY (`S1_Contractee`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Contract` (`Contractee`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `S1_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`S1_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Lawfirm` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Contract and Lawfirm table

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Contract`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Contract` (
  `Date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Contracter` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Contractee` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `Contracter_idx` (`Contracter` ASC),
  INDEX `Contractee_idx` (`Contractee` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Contracter`, `Contractee`, `Date`),
  CONSTRAINT `Contracter`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Contracter`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Agency` (`AgencyID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Contractee`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Contractee`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Agency` (`AgencyID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Lawfirm`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Lawfirm` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I looked through some answers for similar problem but mine columns are same type. I don't understand why it gives me error. I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Check the sql if there is any constraint with the same name. Even it says foreign key error was about constraint names.